# How to move ng-tempate to separate file?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have ng-template with some context bindings:

```
 <ng-template  #radioInputsBlock let-radioInputs="radioInputs" let-elementsInRow="elementsInRow">
...
</ng-template>
```

I want to move it to separate file, to use it in my component markup like this:

```
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="radioInputsBlock;context: {radioInputs: radioInputs.period, elementsInRow: 4}"></ng-container>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: By making a child component? I am not sure however to understand you well

Comment: I dont want to implement child component, because it's no need. I just want to use that ng-template in my view several times with ng-container with different contexts

Comment: why do you want to move it to a separate file?

Comment: because of clean code and ability to reuse it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use `*ngTemplateOutlet`, but this is also works:

**New Template Component - Html:**
you put here **only** the content of your `<ng-template>` like

```
<div>
{{ someInputs }} - {{ elementsInRow }}
</div>
```

**New Template Component - ts:**

```
  @Input()
  someInputs: any;

  @Input()
  elementsInRow: any;
```

**Using from some other Component - Html:**

```
<ng-template #radioInputsBlock let-radioInputs="radioInputs" let-elementsInRow="elementsInRow">
      <app-new-template [someInputs]="someInputs" [radioInputs]="radioInputs"></app-new-template>
</ng-template>
```

*Note:

I used input `someInputs` and `radioInputs` elements like in your example, but any other inputs can be used*